# How to hide Google Apps Script scripts from people who make a copy of a shared Google Sheet and a few questions about protecting ranges and cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet I have been working on. I will share it with others who find the sheet useful when it is complete. What I want to do is prevent others from copying the sheet and getting access to the Google Apps Script scripts that I have paid for which run in the background making this sheet work. I have also protected all of the important formulas in the sheet so that future users cannot edit the cells important formulas are in.

Also, will protecting ranges or cells hide the formulas from other users with a copy of the sheet? Will other users be able to edit those protected ranges and cells once they make a copy of the sheet? I am not really worried about hiding the formulas from people but I am interested in what protecting ranges and cells does in practice because I cannot check for myself what the protected cells do and show because they are not protected from me.

Answer (score 0):

To "hide" the script, put it in a standalone script in your drive and change `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` by

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you, for sharing Mike. I found some info on standalone scripts.

Comment: I have a blank standalone Apps Script project open. Do I simply treat the standalone Apps Script projects as any other project? Can I simply copy and paste my scripts into new standalone Apps Script projects? I went to my Drive > New > Google Apps Script to create a standalone script. How do I find my standalone script if it is not bound to a sheet? Can I click on Apps Script in the top left of the IDE where I can see my Apps Script projects? How can I tell if a script is a standalone script? Also, I am running my scripts from buttons. Can standalone scripts be run by clicking a button?

Comment: I am having problems running the standalone script from a button. I gave the function a unique name and assigned the script to a button but the function could not be found. Is there specific way I am supposed to set this up so that I can run a standalone script from a button?

Comment: You can't launch the standalone script by a button in your sheet AFAIK. You can launch the script by the script editor or by a trigger (for instance, each day, or every x hours)